# Firebug 10.0.2 -- bug with monitoring XMLHttpRequests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firebug

I noticed something strange, i think it is a bug in Firebug.

I try to make an AJAX call, without any jquery, just plain javascript. If the Request gets redirected, in my case from:

```
http://localhost/project/en/?tmpl=ajax
```

to:

```
http://localhost/project/?tmpl=ajax
```

than the firebug console shows the second (redirected) Request as never finished like this:

[image: never ending request]

so the ajax loader icon never stops turning. When I try some other console.log()s, firefox even crashed down when trying to click the logged object.

The next step I tried was something easy: disabling the monitoring of requests, adding events to the XMLHttpRequest object and logging the events. (I added [the events specified here](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/progress/raw-file/tip/Overview.html), via addEventListener).

This resulted in the following output:

[image: logged RequestEvents]

So, everything seems to be fine, because in the net-monitoring-tab I could see that the request should have finished correctly. But looking at the response of the second request showed that there was nothing and clicking on one of the logged Event-Object made firefox crash down again.

I this a bug in firefox, or do I have a terrible mistake at the server side?

EDIT::

I forgot to mention that I even tried all this with jquery.ajax() method. Same never ending Request log in the firebug console.

Comment: From your description indeed looks like a Firebug bug. You can try creating a new Firefox profile and do the same with the older versions of Firebug to see if it's a regression. To assure everything's fine on the server-side, you can use Fiddler (if on Windows), or simply launch the same code in Google Chrome for instance. BTW I guess you have Fbug 1.10.x, not 10.x ;)

Comment: Thank you for reply, later on yesterday I have already tried everything in chrome and safari, where it worked out very fine. So the only "strange guy" is firefox, or better firebug. I think it is a Bug in Firebug.

Comment: IMO you should fill a bug report: https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/I_found_a_Firebug_Bug! http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list